# Pandas: Creating column by applying custom funtions on row level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows

```
ZMONTH    GROUP   ORDER_QTY
201907     A         25
201908     A         23
201909     A         24
201907     B         15
201908     B         0
201909     B         0
```

I want to add another column `ACTIVE` based on the following condition:

```
if ORDER_QTY of last two rows for each group is 0, then ACTIVE==0 else 1
```

So the resultant `df_f` looks like

```
ZMONTH    GROUP   ORDER_QTY   ACTIVE
201907     A         25         1
201908     A         23         1
201909     A         24         1
201907     B         15         0
201908     B         0          0
201909     B         0          0
```

With the above logic, I have tried the following

```
def active_field(row):
   if row.loc[row['ZMONTH']=='201909','ORDER_QTY']==0:
      val=0
   elif row.loc[row['ZMONTH']=='201908','ORDER_QTY']==0:
      val=0
   else:
      val=1
   return val
df['ACTIVE'] = df.apply(active_field,axis=1)
```

The above code is giving `IndexingError: Too many indexers` Error.

Where am I missing?

Comment: I have made a change. from `all()` to `any()`

Comment: I think you can add comment for correct answer by @yatu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `groupby` and check for equality on the last two rows per group, and take `all` on the boolean result. Then just view the resulting boolean arrays as `int8` and assign them to `ACTIVE`:

```
df['ACTIVE'] = (df.groupby('GROUP').ORDER_QTY
                  .transform(lambda x: x.tail(2).ne(0).any())
                  .view('i1'))
```

---

```
print(df)

  ZMONTH GROUP  ORDER_QTY  ACTIVE
0  201907     A         25       1
1  201908     A         23       1
2  201909     A         24       1
3  201907     B         15       0
4  201908     B          0       0
5  201909     B          0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with test last 2 values per group if all values are `0` by [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html):

```
s = df.groupby('GROUP')['ORDER_QTY'].transform(lambda x: x.tail(2).eq(0).all())
df['ACTIVE'] = np.where(s, 0, 1)
print (df)
   ZMONTH GROUP  ORDER_QTY  ACTIVE
0  201907     A         25       1
1  201908     A         23       1
2  201909     A         24       1
3  201907     B         15       0
4  201908     B          0       0
5  201909     B          0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

```
df['ACTIVE'] = (df['GROUP'].map(df.pivot(*df)[::-1].cumsum().iloc[1].ne(0))
                           .astype('int'))
print(df)

   ZMONTH GROUP  ORDER_QTY  ACTIVE
0  201907     A         25       1
1  201908     A         23       1
2  201909     A         24       1
3  201907     B         15       0
4  201908     B          0       0
5  201909     B          0       0
```